# ClassCastException with IWorkbenchPage.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.WorkingSetActionSet")

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

The eclipse bundled with `RCP` thick client has recently upgraded from `Eclise 4.2.2`to `Eclipse Neon 4.6.3`.

With this upgrade, switching perspective gives `ClassCastException` with below code at line `page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.WorkingSetActionSet")`:

```
 private IPerspectiveListener perspectiveListener = new IPerspectiveListener() {
    public void perspectiveActivated(IWorkbenchPage page,
            IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective) {
        // do not show the WorkingSetsactionSet toolbar buttons
        page.hideActionSet("org.eclipse.ui.WorkingSetActionSet"); 
    }
};
```

The exception I get is:

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2021-04-19 17:54:30.409
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.impl.DirectToolItemImpl incompatible with org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MToolBar
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.CoolBarToTrimManager.add(CoolBarToTrimManager.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.CoolBarToTrimManager.insertAfter(CoolBarToTrimManager.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionSetActionBars.getToolBarManager(ActionSetActionBars.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionSetBuilder$ActionSetContribution.contributeAdjunctCoolbarAction(PluginActionSetBuilder.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionSetBuilder.processAdjunctContributions(PluginActionSetBuilder.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginActionSetBuilder.processActionSets(PluginActionSetBuilder.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionPresentation.setActionSets(ActionPresentation.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.updateActionSets(WorkbenchWindow.java:2409)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.hideActionSet(WorkbenchPage.java:2603)
    at org.eclipse.epf.rcp.ui.MainWorkbenchWindowAdvisor$1.perspectiveActivated(MainWorkbenchWindowAdvisor.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList$1.run(PerspectiveListenerList.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.fireEvent(PerspectiveListenerList.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveListenerList.firePerspectiveActivated(PerspectiveListenerList.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.firePerspectiveActivated(WorkbenchWindow.java:1717)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$4.handleEvent(WorkbenchPage.java:3009)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4821)
```

From the above stack trace it looks like there is problem with code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench" which looks like out of control. Is there any way to address this issue?

Comment: Eclipse Neon 4.6.3 is 13 releases and a couple of years behind. Do not wast time with retrocomputing.

Comment: If you can reproduce this on the current Eclipse 2021-03 you could report it as a bug on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/)